# QGIS Server Internal Server Error - OS 109) pipe has been ended. : mod_fcgid: get overlap result error

Tags: installation, qgis-server

I have installed QGIS Server using the [QGIS Server on Windows7 Step-by-step](http://underdark.wordpress.com/2012/04/06/qgis-server-on-windows7-step-by-step/) instructions and when I finished and tried doing `http://localhost:83/qgis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities` I get an error:

```
Internal Server Error    
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.    
Please contact the server administrator, admin@local.domain and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.    
More information about this error may be available in the server error log
```

The log shows:

```
 [Wed Dec 12 22:25:19 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Win32) mod_fcgid/2.3.6 configured  resuming normal operations
[Wed Dec 12 22:25:19 2012] [notice] Server built: Sep 28 2009 22:41:08
[Wed Dec 12 22:25:20 2012] [notice] Parent: Created child process 3868
[Wed Dec 12 22:25:20 2012] [notice] Child 3868: Child process is running
[Wed Dec 12 22:25:20 2012] [notice] Child 3868: Acquired the start mutex.
[Wed Dec 12 22:25:20 2012] [notice] Child 3868: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed Dec 12 22:25:21 2012] [notice] Child 3868: Starting thread to listen on port 83.
[Wed Dec 12 22:26:08 2012] [warn] [client 127.0.0.1] (OS 109)The pipe has been ended.  : mod_fcgid: get overlap result error
[Wed Dec 12 22:26:08 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Premature end of script headers: qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe
[Wed Dec 12 22:26:09 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/OSGeo4W/apache/htdocs/favicon.ico
```

What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found out when double clicked "qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe" that libfcgi.dll was missing.
problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error log in Apache except for the last row.. I ran the `qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe` in cmd and found out that the program missed python modules:

> ImportError: No module named site

I simply copied all modules + the folder named encoding FROM `C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\Lib` TO  `C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\bin`

Answer (score 1):

I simply copied all modules + the folder named encoding FROM C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\Lib TO C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\bin

This worked for me after long search !!

Answer (score 1):

For QGIS server version 3 (64bit), there were several settings that I had to change (april 2018):

The libxml2 that comes with Apache 2.4 (64bit) is not compatible with QGIS server. If you run QGIS server with Apache, Apache will pre-load its own version of libxml2 and you'll get an error about a missing xmlNanoHTMLCleanup entry point.
Fix this as follows:

```
copy Apache24\bin\libxml2.dll Apache24\bin\libxml2.dll.org
copy OSGeo4W64\bin\libxml2.dll Apache24\bin\libmxml2.dll
```

QGIS 3+ switched from QT4 to QT5, also they moved to Python 3+. You have to update your Apache24\conf\extra\httpd_qgis.conf file to look something like this:

```
LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so

FcgidIOTimeout 120
FcgidInitialEnv PATH "C:\OSGeo4W64\bin;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\bin;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Qt5\bin;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\grass\grass-@grassversion@\bin;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\grass\grass-@grassversion@\lib;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem"
FcgidInitialEnv QGIS_PREFIX_PATH "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis"
FcgidInitialEnv QT_PLUGIN_PATH "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\qtplugins;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Qt5\plugins;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qt4\plugins"
FcgidInitialEnv TEMP "C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp"
FcgidInitialEnv PYTHONHOME "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python36"

FcgidInitialEnv QGIS_DEBUG 1
FcgidInitialEnv QGIS_SERVER_LOG_FILE C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\qgis-000.log
FcgidInitialEnv QGIS_SERVER_LOG_LEVEL 0

Alias /qgis/ C:\OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis/bin/

<Directory "C:\OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis/bin/">
    SetHandler fcgid-script
    Options ExecCGI
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

After restarting Apache, put a qgis project file (yourproject.qgs) in the c:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\bin directory and test with:

http://localhost/qgis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?map=yourproject.qgs&service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=getcapabilities

Comment: In new QGIS there is Python 3.7 not 3.6. So To make it work change PYTHONHOME  to "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python37"   

There is no need to swap libxml2.dll file

Answer (score 0):

adding the lines

```
SetEnv PYTHONHOME "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27"
SetEnv PYTHONPATH "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\python"
```

to the configuration file

```
C:\OSGeo4W\httpd.d\httpd_qgis.conf
```

solved the python issue for me (Win 2008 R2)